# Is it possible to get out of this Nuget Hell scenario?

Tags: c#, azure, nuget, azure-functions, nuget-package

I want my project to have the following packages

- Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus
- Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions
- .NETStandard Library
- Newtonsoft.Json

Right now I have the most recent versions

- Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus (3.1.1)
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions (3.0.0)
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage (3.0.0)
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus (v3.0.0-beta8)
- Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions (1.0.22)
- .NETStandard Library (2.0.1)
- Newtonsoft.Json(11.0.2)

Which have the following dependencies of WebJobs:

- Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus [None]
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs (>= 3.0.0)]
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs (>= 3.0.0)]
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs (= 2.2.0)]
- Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs (>= 3.0.0 && < 3.1.0)]
- .NETStandard Library [None]
- Newtonsoft.Json [None]

Interestingly, Visual Studio isn't flagging this as a problem (no yellow triangles in Solution Explorer), even though there are clearly conflicting version requirements. When I try to build my Function App project I get the error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot
>   find the file specified. File name: 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs,
>   Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'    at
>   System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken,
>   IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs,
>   Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type)    at
>   System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module,
>   Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext,
>   RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken,
>   Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)    at
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord
>   caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly,
>   RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken,
>   RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[]
>   attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType,
>   IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean&
>   isVarArg)    at
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule
>   decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount,
>   RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList
>   derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent)    at
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeParameterInfo
>   parameter, RuntimeType caType)    at
>   System.Attribute.InternalParamGetCustomAttributes(ParameterInfo param,
>   Type type, Boolean inherit)    at
>   MakeFunctionJson.ParameterInfoExtensions.GetDisabledAttribute(ParameterInfo
>   parameterInfo)    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>
>   at MakeFunctionJson.MethodInfoExtensions.GetDisabled(MethodInfo
>   method)    at
>   MakeFunctionJson.MethodInfoExtensions.HasUnsuportedAttributes(MethodInfo
>   method, String& error)    at
>   MakeFunctionJson.FunctionJsonConverter.<GenerateFunctions>d__9.MoveNext()
>   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   MakeFunctionJson.FunctionJsonConverter.TryGenerateFunctionJsons()
>   at MakeFunctionJson.FunctionJsonConverter.TryRun()
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>
> Error generating functions metadata

Any way out of this Nuget Hell or can I not use all these packages? I've tried looking at previous versions and there seems to be no way to get them all to agree on a version of WebJobs. How does one typically resolve these situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus`, the new package is now called  `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus(3.0.0)`. See [package references](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Updating-your-function-app-extensions#what-nuget-packages-do-i-need) in v2 functions.

Besides, `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions(1.0.22)` contains `Newtonsoft.Json(11.0.2)` and `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions (3.0.0)`, no need to install them separately. And `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus(3.0.0)` contains `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus(3.0.2)` as well, you don't need to install it either as long as the latest version is not necessary.

For example, you can create a v2 servicebus trigger template in VS and only need to add  `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage (3.0.0)` to achieve your goal.